# How can I resolve these problems with numbers?

Tags: vim, floating-point, numbers, integer, exponential

I still have troubles with numbers in Vim:

p.e.

```
let a = 1.02 | let b = '10000000' | let total = a*b | echo total --> 1.02e7
```

I would like to avoid Exponentials.
How can I have the output 10200000 ?

```
let a = 4000000000 | let b = '1' | let total = a+b | echo total  --> -294967295
```

Why does this give a wrong output?

Tnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `printf`:

```
let a = 1.02 | let b = '10000000' | let total = a*b | echo printf( "%.f", total)
```

Output:

```
10200000
```

Answer (score 2):

```
:echo printf("%.0f", 4000000000.0 + 1.0)
```

Points to note:

- You're using string->int conversion to do your arithmetic, which is not a good thing normally.
- ints are machine word sized, so large numbers will overflow, especially on 32 bit machines.
- floating point numbers format using %g usually, if you want to control precision use printf.
- use floats if you are going to be dealing with large numbers, although that really won't be great if you expect exact precision.

Comment: I noted that "%.0f" has a limit also. `echo printf("%.0f", 200303004040050500500600.0 + 1.0)` gives as output `2003030040400505000000000` -- 16 numbers?

Comment: floats have a maximum precision of around 7 decimal places, if they are 32 bit floats. You really won't be able to do 'big number' arithmetic in vim directly. Consider using Python longs if you're using very large integers.

Answer (score 2):

Overflow is easily seen by

```
:let a = 4000000000 | echo a --> -294967296
```